# Average days of inventory

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Вant to calculate average number of days an inventory is in stock. I'm trying to use a datediff as follows

```
select col1, col2, date_diff(current_date(), inventory_date, day) 
from table1
```

however the query doesn't run and gives an error on the `date_diff` command.

How do i tackle this?

Comment: (1) SQL Server or Big Query? Please tag only one database. (2) Which error message do you get exactly?

Comment: I've removed [tag:sql-server], as this is clearly not SQL Server based on the above. `DATE_DIFF` is not a function in T-SQL (it's `DATEDIFF`), and neither is `CURRENT_DATE()`. If this *were* T-SQL, the the `DATEDIFF` parameters are also in the wrong order. if this is SQL Server, I would suggest these are typographical errors, compounded by a lack of research: [DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: What's data type is used for `col1` and `col2`? Take a look here: [DATE_DIFF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_diff)

Comment: I am using bigquery for this. and the data types are as follows
col1 - text
col2- int
col3 - int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the query below over a table generated with three columns `col1: STRING`, `col2: INT64` and `inventory_date: DATE` and, to my understanding, the [DATE_DIFF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_diff) statement is behaving as expected.

```
WITH t as (
  SELECT 'car' as col1, 1 as col2, DATE(2020,1,1) as inventory_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'table' as col1, 10 as col2, DATE(2020,2,10) as inventory_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'chair' as col1, 4 as col2, DATE(2020,7,4) as inventory_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'car2' as col1, 20 as col2, DATE(2019,12,31) as inventory_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TV' as col1, 0 as col2, DATE(2020,8,10) as inventory_date
  )
SELECT 
  col1, 
  col2,
  inventory_date,
  DATE_DIFF(current_date(), inventory_date, day)
FROM t
```

When using `DATE_DIFF`, please make sure that the fields inside the function have the proper `DATE` type, otherwise the following error will be thrown:

```
No matching signature for function DATE_DIFF for argument types: DATE, INT64, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: DATE_DIFF(DATE, DATE, DATE_TIME_PART) at [16:3]
```